# What's the best way to search a number and replace it after calculation in a string by Python?

Tags: python, string, replace

For example. I have a string: "[bezierPath moveToPoint: CGPointMake(7.98, 6.11)];". I want to do some calculation on the two float number and replace them.

Comment: Why are you using Python to edit Objective-C files? Are you trying to find and replace in multiple locations?

Comment: @thegrinner Yes, I want do some code generation by Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `re.sub`:

```
>>> import re
>>> def action(matchObj):
...     return str(float(matchObj.group(0)) * 2)
... 
>>> re.sub('\d+\.\d+', action, "[bezierPath moveToPoint: CGPointMake(7.98, 6.11)];")
'[bezierPath moveToPoint: CGPointMake(15.96, 12.22)];'
```

Answer (score 1):

May not be the best way, you can get the those two float numbers like this, and do the calculation:

```
>>> a
'[bezierPath moveToPoint: CGPointMake(7.98, 6.11)];'
>>> x = a.split('(')[1]
>>> x
'7.98, 6.11)];'
>>> y = x.split(')')[0]
>>> y
'7.98, 6.11'
>>> first_no = float(y.split(',')[0])
>>> first_no
7.98
>>> second_no = float(y.split(',')[1])
>>> second_no
6.11
>>> result = first_no - second_no
```

Now use the following syntax to replace the string:

```
a.replace('CGPointMake(7.98, 6.11)', str(result))
```